# Count duplicates (by assigning numbers) without grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
Name
-----
A  
A  
B  
D  
R  
A  
B
```

Want to add a column that will count the entries by assigning ordered numbers like this:

```
Name   Count
--------------
A        1
A        2
B        1
D        1
R        1
A        3
B        2
```

Comment: Do you any other column like id, date on which the sort order should work?

Answer (score 7):

Your table seems to be lacking a column which would provide an ordering for the counts you are expecting.  Since each entry is equivalent to the other, we can just order by `Name` and use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) Count
FROM yourTable;
```

I also don't see any obvious ordering your expected result set.  You would need a column(s) in order to impose an ordering there, too.

Comment: well this is quite impressive, but i don't think that is appropriate according to the question! when you are using order by, the order of the name should be arranged, that was not needed in question, I think. the order of name shouldn't be altered!